# How to show an array of 2d points/polygons in Polymaps (Cartesian coordinate system)

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, polymaps

I need to display these 2d points/polygons (Cartesian coordinate system) on Polymaps with GeoJson layer.
I do not use the other layers.

Do I need to convert xy coordinates to the lat lon? If so, how?
How to use Cartesian coordinate system in Polymaps?